# Can I view which communities I am not a member of?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, user-accounts

I want to try finding new Stack Exchange communities that I haven't participated in before.

My [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/4030991/steven-vascellaro?tab=accounts) includes my complete list of communities, but I can't find a way of seeing which communities I haven't joined yet.

**How can I see which SE communities I have not participated in?**

Comment: Is there something you don't like about simply scrolling through the drop-down menu?

Comment: @Catija what drop down menu? The one in the top bar is showing all of them, without indicating if you have account there or not.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Certainly the OP would know if they haven't participated in a site...

Comment: @Catija no, that's the whole point here... and to be honest it's the same for me. I joined most sites I have account on just to flag spam (reported by Smokey), and have no idea where I have account and where I don't have, when looking in the full sites list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I happen to have written a SEDE query for that. You can find it [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/628471/sites-where-a-user-doesnt-have-an-account-on). It contains (non-formatted, HTTP) URLs to the sites so you can register yourself with three clicks or so. It will also show you the sites you *do* have an account on further down the list.

Note that the data is refreshed every Sunday morning (UTC), so it might be a bit outdated.

Comment: TIL there's a Stack Exchange for [Reverse Engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Another option, without SEDE, is using AJAX to grab the list of your accounts and compare it with the list of all SE sites, extracting those where you don't have account in.

When on any page on stackexchange.com domain, you can execute the following script via the browser developer console: (e.g. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> in Chrome)

```js
console.log("Getting your accounts list...");
$.get("/users/current?tab=accounts").then(function(rawAccountsHTML) {
    var accountsList = $(rawAccountsHTML).find(".account-site");
    console.log("Found " + accountsList.length + " sites");
    console.log("Getting list of all Stack Exchange sites...");
    $.get("/sites").then(function(rawAllSitesHTML) {
        var allSitesList = $(rawAllSitesHTML).find(".lv-info");
        console.log("Found total of " + allSitesList.length + " sites in Stack Exchange");
        var accountNames = accountsList.map(function() { return $.trim($(this).find("a").first().text()); }).get();
        var allSiteNames = allSitesList.map(function() { return $.trim($(this).find("a").first().text()); }).get();
        var accountMapping = {};
        accountNames.forEach(function(name) { accountMapping[name] = true; });
        var sitesWithoutAccount = allSiteNames.filter(function(name) { return !accountMapping[name]; });
        console.log("You don't have account on the following sites: " + sitesWithoutAccount.join(", "));
    }, function(err) {
        console.log("Error getting list of all sites");
    });
}, function(err) {
    console.log("Error getting accounts list");
});
```

Sample output:

> [image]